# Dudas sobre la función isascii

Tags: c++

Me dejaron como trabajo investigar algunas funciones de las librerías del C/C++. En este caso me he topado con la función `isascii` de la librería `ctype.h`. Buscando en Google he encontrado que se utiliza para determinar si un carácter de tipo `int` *puede ser representado como un carácter 7-bit US ASCII*.

La verdad no entiendo exactamente a que se refiere lo anterior. Además he encontrado el siguiente [código](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rtref/isascii.htm) (el cual está en C y lo cambié a C++):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ch;

    for(ch=0x7c; ch<=0x82; ch++)
    {
        cout << ch;
        cout << "\n";
        if(isascii(ch))
            cout << "El caracter es:\t" << ch << "\n" << endl;
        else
            cout << "No se puede representar por un caracter ASCII.\n" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A la hora de compilarlo me sale algo diferente a lo que supuestamente debe salir (según el código original en C). Además tampoco entiendo la sentencia `if(isascii(ch))`. Está realizando alguna especie de comparación?

Muchas gracias de antemano por sus comentarios y/o respuestas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La función [`isascii`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isascii) está [deprecada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) desde 2008, por ello no recibe soporte y su comportamiento no tiene por qué ser ni el documentado ni el esperado.

En los sistemas modernos no tiene sentido alguno comprobar si un valor es o no es [ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) pues se basan en sistemas de codificación que van más allá de los límites de ASCII o trabajan con caracteres cuyo tipo subyacente tiene una profundidad mayor de 8 bits o incluso con caracteres multibyte (como la familia [UTF-8](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)).

Por otro lado, dicha función es fácil de implementar pues basta con comprobar si el valor recibido es menor a 127, aunque como he mencionado antes: es una comprobación sin sentido

---

> Tampoco entiendo la sentencia `if(isascii(ch))`. ¿Está realizando alguna especie de comparación?

La función `isascii` devuelve un valor diferente a `0` en caso de que el valor sea presuntamente ASCII o `0` en caso contrario. El lenguaje C++ permite la conversión implícita de valores numéricos a [valores booleanos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipo_de_dato_l%C3%B3gico) si estos valores son usados en un contexto en que se espera un booleano (como por ejemplo una sentencia `if`). Esta conversión implícita transforma a verdadero (`true`) cualquier valor diferente a `0` y falso (`false`) el valor `0`.

Por lo tanto la sentencia condicional `if(isascii(ch))` entrará en el cuerpo del `if` cuando `isascii(ch)` sea verdadero, que como hemos visto será cuando devuelva un valor diferente de `0`. Esa sentencia es funcionalmente idéntica a:

```
//  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <-- el retorno de isascii es diferente de cero?
if (isascii(ch) != 0)
    std::cout << "El caracter es:\t" << ch << "\n\n";
else
    std::cout << "No se puede representar por un caracter ASCII.\n\n";
```